# Error 404 using axios, react native and iphone 14 pro only

Tags: ios, react-native, axios

I developed an app using react native 0.72.6 and axios 1.5.0.
The app uses an https API on port 8080.
On Android it works normally on several devices, on the iPhone 6, iPhone 8 and iPhone 12 it also works but on the iPhone 14 Pro and the iPhone 14 Pro emulator the same url returns the 404 error.
I have already updated axios to the latest version but the error remains.
Publishing the same API on the default port, 443, works on all devices and emulators

Comment: Because they need secure url for security reasons. Try using https with SSL certificate it will work. In production if your domain has SSL it will work. For development you can use tunnel with SSL.

Comment: It is already configured like this, the only difference is that it uses port 8080 instead of 443